# How to order data with Symfony and Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, datagrid

I want to build datagrid filter but `->addOrderBy` amd `->orderBy` don't work for me.

```
$query
    ->andWhere('o.pizza = :pizza')
    ->setParameter('pizza', $pizzaId)
    ->addOrderBy(o.status,'ASC')
```

How ever if I do this:

```
$query
    ->andWhere('o.pizza = :spizza')
    ->setParameter('pizza', $pizzaId)
    ->andWhere('o.status = :status')
    ->setParameter('status',Pizza\PizzaApply::STATUS_READY)
```

It shows me only the pizzas with status 'ready'. But I want to sort by status 'ready' shoulde first and 'On hold' under them.

Comment: Is this code an actual copy of your real code? If it is the issue you have with your orderby is the lack of quotes..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem really recently and managed to sort it out using this in my Admin Class: (in my case I wanted a double order)

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->orderby('o.dateUpdated DESC, o.name');
    return $query;
}
```

As an alternative, you can also use that in your Admin class:

```
/**
 * Default Datagrid values
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $datagridValues = array(
    '_page' => 1,
    '_sort_order' => 'DESC',
    '_sort_by' => 'dateUpdated'
);
```

Comment: I was overriden by '_sort_by' in protected $datagridValues. Everything isfine now.